# Check request parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, http, http-headers

I want to check request header parameters. If an attribute is missing , I don't accept the request.

Current implementation is here:

```
class SampleController < ApplicationController
    before_action :render_message, unless: :check_header
    // GET method 
    def index
        ....
    end

    def check_header
        return request.headers["key1"] && request.headers["key2"] && request.headers["key3"]
    end

    def render_message
        render json: { message: "missing the custom attribute in the header" }, status:400
    end
```

How can I beautify this code?

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? That the keys are in the header? That there a specific or at least non-blank values set?

Comment: @spickermann They are must be specified and non-blank values

Comment: At the moment you do not check that the values match any specified list of allowed values. What kind of values will be allowed, how is a valid value defined? Is there a whitelist or a regexp to check against?

Comment: Types of them are string. null or empty string check is enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably rewrite the method to something like this:

```
def check_header
  required_headers = %w[key2 key2 key3]
  required_headers.all? { |key| request.headers[key] }
end
```

Note that the above version has the same behavior then your example. If you really need to check that the values are present (an empty string is still true-ish) then you will need to check `present?` too.

```
def check_header
  required_headers = %w[key2 key2 key3]
  required_headers.all? { |key| request.headers[key].present? }
end
```

And I would think about using a constant instead of the local variable `required_headers`.

Comment: @moveson I think the OP is not clear on the requirements. The code in the question would allow blank strings, whereas in the comment the OP wrote that blank values might be invalid. I updated my answer to address this.